# Android app crashes before intent is launched

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm creating my first android app, so I'm really a beginner with (android) development.

The first fase of the app is to implement an Activity (i.e. BleActivity.java), which is called when a certain button is clicked. The BleActivity should list available BLE devices (testing with a tiSensorTag CC2650) and later on I want to read the data from the devices.

It was quite a challenge to get it to work because most of the tutorials online are written with deprecated API's. After combining several tutorials, the app is now working!

There is one bug in the app which I'm unable to fix:

When bluetooth is **turned off** and I trigger the BleActivity, the onResume() checks if bluetooth is enabled (which is not the case) and if it's not, a dialog screen appears requesting the user to turn bluetooth on.

### I can see the dialog screen but before I'm able to use it, the app crashes.

---

BleActivity.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BleActivity extends ListActivity {

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

    // see nested class LeDeviceListAdapter
    private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner;
    private ScanSettings settings;
    private List<ScanFilter> filters;

    private static final String INFO = "ZINFO";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Check if BLE is supported
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            Log.i(INFO, "onCreate: BLE is supported");
        }
        // Create a Handler to send and process Message Class and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue.
        mHandler = new Handler();

        // Get BluetoothManager and BluetoothAdapter in order to conduct overall Bluetooth Management.
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Initialize list view adapter
        mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);

        //Check if permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION (AndroidManifest.xml) is granted.
        if (checkLocationPermission()) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.grant_permission, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            } else {
                Log.i(INFO, "onResume: Permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION is granted");
            }
        }

        // Check if bluetoothAdapter is successfully obtained and if BLE is enabled.
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } else {
            Log.i(INFO, "onResume: BLE is enabled");
        }
        // GET getBluetoothLeScanner(): This class provides methods to perform scan related operations for Bluetooth LE devices
        mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        // Set scan settings
        settings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED).build();
        // Set device filter (null is allowed)
        filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();

        // START SCAN FOR BLE DEVICES!
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }

    // When user denies prompt for enabling Bluetooth, the Activity is closed
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                finish();
                return;
            }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    // Pause scanning for BLE devices */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scanLeDevice(false);
        mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
    }

    //Methods for permission check
    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle(R.string.title_location_permission)
                        .setMessage(R.string.text_location_permission)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BleActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();
            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.i(INFO, "onRequestPermissionsResult: PERMISSION_GRANTED");
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    // Methods for START & STOP scan
    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback); //STOP SCANNING
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD); // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.

            mScanning = true;
            mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback); //START SCANNING
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback); //STOP SCANNING
        }
        if(mScanning == true) {
            //TODO: Implement code for when the app is scanning (green stoplight, turning wheel, etc.)
        } else {
            //TODO: Implement code for when the app is NOT scanning (red stoplight, idle wheel, etc.)
        }
    }
    // Bluetooth LE scan results are reported using these callbacks.
    private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
            mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(btDevice);
            mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            for (ScanResult sr : results) {
                Log.i("ScanResult - Results", sr.toString());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            Log.e("Scan Failed", "Error Code: " + errorCode);
        }
    };

    // ListAdapter for holding devices found through scanning.
    private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
        private LayoutInflater mInflator;

        public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
            super();
            mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            mInflator = BleActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        }

        public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            if(!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
                mLeDevices.add(device);
            }
        }

        /*
        TODO: implement onListItemClick (see example code)
        public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
            return mLeDevices.get(position);
        }*/

        public void clear() {
            mLeDevices.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mLeDevices.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return mLeDevices.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            // General ListView optimization code.
            if (view == null) {
                view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_ble, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
                viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
            final String deviceName = device.getName();
            if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
            else
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
                viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());

            return view;
        }
    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView deviceName;
        TextView deviceAddress;
    }
}
```

Your help is much appreciated and please keep in mind that this is my first app and I'm still an amateur/beginner developer.

---

logcat:

```
08-06 16:21:39.152 5489-5489/nl.cargosys.iotcloudconnect E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: nl.cargosys.iotcloudconnect, PID: 5489
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {nl.cargosys.iotcloudconnect/nl.cargosys.iotcloudconnect.BleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:4179)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4145)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4119)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4093)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1654)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at nl.cargosys.iotcloudconnect.BleActivity.scanLeDevice(BleActivity.java:179)
                                                                               at nl.cargosys.iotcloudconnect.BleActivity.onPause(BleActivity.java:121)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:7148)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1330)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:4168)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4145) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4119) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4093) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1654) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: post logcat error here to better help.

Comment: post logcat here

Comment: May I suggest that you add a breakpoint in your `BleActivity` and pinpoint the exact line of code where the app crashes?  This would be very helpful to someone reading this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your if condition below -

```
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
```

The main problem lies in your -

```
mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    // Set scan settings
    settings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED).build();
    // Set device filter (null is allowed)
    filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();

    // START SCAN FOR BLE DEVICES!
    scanLeDevice(true);
```

You check if the adapter is available and if not you start another activity for result, but you continue to do the operation in your scanner code and scan for device after your else. Ideally you should place the above code in your else statement and only start scanning device if you are 100% sure that you have Bluetooth enabled.

**Update 1**

Ok so this error is coming from your `onPause()` method where you are calling `scanLeDevice(false);`  method. Now inside this method you do `mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);` but your mLEScanner is not yet initialized as the initialization code is in your else statement or after it in the line

```
mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
```

So it is better if you do this in your method-

```
if(mLEScanner!=null)
{
   mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have placed the code in the else statement but I still have the same issue. The app crashes and after the crash, the dialog for turning Bluetooth on is opened.

Comment: How do I add the logcat to this topic? Sorry, also the first time using this forum :)

Comment: I see a lot of errors but I'm not allowed to paste all of them. I have included the errors which seems the most relevant for my issue.

Comment: Note that as soon as you do startActivity your current activity gets paused and hence your onPause will be called by default. So you need to handle that scenario accordingly. @Maarten

Comment: Thanks!! I should learn to use the logcat more. I understand the issue now. I have added your suggested logic to the onPause() instead of the scanLeDevice method. It seems to work fine now, any issues with adding it to the onPause() instead of the method?

Comment: Yes even this approach makes sense. So if this solved the problem please accept my answer @Maarten